# Should 'best answer' be replaced with 'helpful answer'?

Tags: discussion

When you hover with your mouse on the green accept mark on an answer, you get the tooltip

> The question owner accepted this as the best answer

Shouldn't it be:

> The question owner accepted this answer as helpful

Because on the [StackOverflow About Page](https://stackoverflow.com/about), you can read:

> Accepting **doesn't mean it's the best answer**, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accepted means it was the best answer *for the question owner*.  It doesn't mean it's the best answer *for the community as a whole*.

Comment: And that's not what the tooltip is saying. It's just saying `it's the best answer` which could be either for the question owner or the community.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Sure it is.  "The ***question owner*** accepted this as the best answer"

Comment: It should be worded the same way everywhere, the tooltip could say "The question owner accepted this as the working answer" as it might not be the "best" answer.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It's the best answer *in the eyes of the question owner*, so the tooltip is correct in that regard.

Comment: The current tooltip is not clearly stating that out of all doubts. It only says the owner accepted it as the best answer, no where does it implies that it is only for him/herself. Having  homogeneous wording would clear any possible doubts of the meaning of the green check.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau If you have a proposed wording change that you think is clearer, *but that is still correct*, then by all means.  So far all of the proposed changes would change it to mean something that it doesn't mean.